# javascript: pass an object as the argument to a onclick function inside string

Tags: javascript, argument-passing

I would like to pass an object as parameter to an Onclick function inside a string. Something like follwing:

```
function myfunction(obj,parentobj){ 
   var o=document.createElement("div");
   o.innerHTML='<input type="button" onclick="somelistener(' + obj + ')" />';
   parentobj.appendChild(o.firstChild);
}
```

Obviously, this doesn't work. Anyone has any idea? THX!

A more complete version, as suggested by @Austin

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<style type="text/css">

</style>
<p id="test">test</p>
<p id="objectid"></p>

<script>
function test(s){
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML+=s;
}

function somelistener(obj){
    test(obj.id);
}

function myfunction(obj,parentobj){ 
    var o=document.createElement("div");
    o.innerHTML='<input type="button" onclick="somelistener(' + obj + ')" />';

    o.onclick = function () {
        someListener(obj)
    }
parentobj.appendChild(o.firstChild);
}

myfunction(document.getElementById("objectid"),document.getElementById("test"));

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Austin I am not sure if I understand your answer correct. But as I tried in complete version above, it does not work either. Could you see the problem?

Comment: @scott.korin Thx Scott. But after I changed the capitalization, it still does not work.

Comment: @Austin BTW, even if I change o.onclick to o.firstChild.onclick, that does not work either, if that is potentially a problem.

Comment: Can you be a little more specific? What exactly is not working?

Comment: Should work fine, see my jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/RDVHr/)

Comment: Got it, thx! Does that mean there is no way to declare onclick function with obj as parameter inside the string?

Comment: No problem, be sure to click the check next to my answer if you feel I best answered your question. And no, there is no _efficient_ method to do it the way you originally tried.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The above example does not work because the output of `obj` to text is `[Object object]`, so essentially, you are calling `someListener([Object object])`.

While you have the instance of the element in `o`, bind to it's click using javascript:

```
function myfunction(obj,parentobj){ 
    var o=document.createElement("div");
    o.innerHTML='<input type="button" />';

    o.onClick = function () {
        someListener(obj)
    }

    parentobj.appendChild(o.firstChild);
}
```

I have created a working fiddle for you here: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RDVHr/)

Answer (score 15):

Old question whose answers I didn't quite understand, but the simplest solution is to combine the functions `encodeURIComponent` and `JSON.stringify`, that is, you stringify the object and then escape those special characters, and then reverse the process inside the function

```js
var obj = {a: 'hey there', b: 1}

document.getElementById('mydiv').innerHTML =
  `<button onclick="myFunction('${encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(obj))}')">Click me</button>`

function myFunction(obj) {
  console.log(JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent(obj)))
}
```

```html
<div id="mydiv"></div>
```

Comment: this is the currect answer ,

Answer (score 10):

```
function myfunction(obj,parentobj){ 
        var o=document.createElement("div");
         o.innerHTML="<input type='button' onclick='somelistener("+JSON.stringify(obj)+")'/>"; 
                                  parentobj.appendChild(o.firstChild);
            } 
    // my similar problem, function a was called in a jsonArray loop in the dataTable initiation
    function a(data, type, obj) {
                         var str = "";
                         str += "<span class='button-group'>";
                         str +="<a onclick='chooseData1("+JSON.stringify(obj)+")'>[选择]</a>";
                         str += "</span>";
                         return str;
                                            }
function chooseData1(data){
                        console.log(data);
                  }
```

Comment: I have a similar problem and I fix it in this way

Comment: Beware, if the object contains characters like ' it may corrupt hour HTML.

Answer (score 3):

Just stringify the object using JSON.stringify(obj) and pass into the onclick function as parameter and it will be parsed directly and received in the function as Object.

```
function myfunction(obj,parentobj){ 
   var o=document.createElement("div");
   // stringify the object
   var stringifiedObj = JSON.stringify(obj)

   o.innerHTML='<input type="button" onclick=`somelistener(${stringifiedObj})` />';
   parentobj.appendChild(o);
}

function somelistener(obj){
   console.log(typeof obj) //Object
}
```

Answer (score -10):

Just do pass it like this :

```
o.innerHTML='<input type="button" onclick="somelistener(this)" />';
```

Comment: Passing 'this' won't work. The object passed is definitely *not* identifiable by 'this'. Downvoted.