# Efficient way to pass an Object to onclick method html

Tags: javascript, html, object

I have recently discovered an issue where I am not allowed to pass an object parameter to an `onclick()` method.

I did some research and it seems to be a popular issue. I have read this:
[javascript: pass an object as the argument to a onclick function inside string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12109811/javascript-pass-an-object-as-the-argument-to-a-onclick-function-inside-string)
and I tried to stringify the object before passing to an `onclick()` but that does not seem to work.

[image]

My code:

```
        var object_info= {
            TypeID:11000,
            TypeValue:5,
            ValueID:12103,
            ValueValue:15,
            CorrectionID:11020,
            CorrectionValue:0,
            LabelStr:Analog_input_name[11000],
            TypeStr:InputATypeStr[5],
            DivId:"Test123",
        };

        Append_html_block(object_info);
```

The `Append_html_block` function:

```
function Append_html_block(object) {
    var generated_html = document.getElementById("custom_DIV");
    var stringifiedObj = JSON.stringify(object);

    generated_html .innerHTML += `
    <table class="sensor-values-table">
        <tr>
        <td class="top-item" style="width:90%;">${object.LabelStr}</td>
            <td>
                <button style="border:none;background-color:inherit;" onclick="Expand_selection(${stringifiedObj})">
       
                </button>
            </td>
        </tr>

    </table>
<br>
`;
}
```

The logic is very simple:
I create an object which I pass to `Append_html_block` function. Inside this function, I have a button. If this button is clicked, I want to perform specific actions and in order to do these actions I must know all the information about the object so I need to pass the object variable.

I didin't manage to find a clear and simple solution for passing an ojbect variable to `onclick()`. Perhaps someone can suggest a neat and clean method for doing that? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why instead of doing this, simple don't use an array of Object Info and a data-attribute with some unique IDS?

Comment: Can you please provide a simple example as I am not fully certain understood what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

It is generally [not a good idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871640/why-is-using-onclick-in-html-a-bad-practice) to use inline event handlers.

You can try handling the button using [event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation).

Here is a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of it.

```js
document.addEventListener(`click`, handle);
const object_info = {
  TypeID: 11000,
  TypeValue: 5,
  ValueID: 12103,
  ValueValue: 15,
  CorrectionID: 11020,
  CorrectionValue: 0,
  LabelStr: `EXAMPLE-Analog_input_name[11000]`,
  TypeStr: `EXAMPLE-InputATypeStr[5]`,
  DivId: 'Test123',
};

Append_html_block(object_info);

function handle(evt) {
  if (evt.target.dataset.expand) {
    evt.target.closest(`td`).querySelector(`pre`).classList.toggle(`hidden`);
  }
}

function Append_html_block(object) {
  var stringifiedObj = JSON.stringify(object, null, 2);
  document.querySelector(`#generated`).insertAdjacentHTML(`beforeend`,
    `<table class="sensor-values-table">
      <tr>
        <td>${object.LabelStr}</td>
        <td>
          <button data-expand="1">Expand/Hide</button>
          <pre class="hidden">${stringifiedObj}</pre>
        </td>
      </tr>
   </table>`);
}
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}

td {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div id="generated"></div>
```

Comment: `<pre class="hidden">${stringifiedObj}</pre>` — This seems like something far better suited to a `data-*` attribute. The JSON isn't going to be displayed raw to the user is it?

Answer (score 0):

As I said in my comment you can use a unique ID (I used `TypeID`) to call the source object like:

```js
const objctInfo = [{
    TypeID: 11000,
    TypeValue: 5,
    ValueID: 12103,
    ValueValue: 15,
    CorrectionID: 11020,
    CorrectionValue: 0,
    LabelStr: 1,
    TypeStr: 5,
    DivId: "Test123",
  },
  {
    TypeID: 11001,
    TypeValue: 5,
    ValueID: 12103,
    ValueValue: 15,
    CorrectionID: 11020,
    CorrectionValue: 0,
    LabelStr: 2,
    TypeStr: 5,
    DivId: "Test124",
  },
];
objctInfo.forEach(Append_html_block);

function Append_html_block(obj) { 
    var generated_html = document.getElementById("custom_DIV");

    generated_html .innerHTML += `
    <table class="sensor-values-table" border=1>
        <tr>
        <td class="top-item" style="width:90%;">${obj.LabelStr}</td>
            <td>
                <button style="border:none;background-color:inherit;" onclick="Expand_selection(${obj.TypeID})">
        click me
                </button>
            </td>
        </tr>

    </table>
<br>
`;
}

function Expand_selection(id){
  const obj = objctInfo.find(obj => obj.TypeID === parseInt(id));
  console.log(obj);
}
```

```html
<div id="custom_DIV"></div>
```

Comment: Please can you clarify my few concerns regarding this method: 
1. This method will only work if the object is declared globally (need to ensure expand_selection method have access to the object). 
2. Additionally, what would happen if I have multiple objects for example objcetInfo1, objectInfo2, objectInfo3 and etc...?

Comment: 1. Yes (just use a variable `let`) 2. Just group all object in one array like my example

Answer (score -1):

From an answer to the similar question you linked to, try using the `encodeURIComponent` function on the returned value from `JSON.stringify` and then where the object is needed, do the reverse process: use the `JSON.parse` function on the returned value of the `decodeURIComponent` function:

```
function Append_html_block(object) { // try appendHtmlBlock instead (Camel Case
    var generated_html = document.getElementById("custom_DIV");
    var encodedObj = encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(object));

    generated_html .innerHTML += `
    <table class="sensor-values-table">
        <tr>
        <td class="top-item" style="width:90%;">${object.LabelStr}</td>
            <td>
                <button style="border:none;background-color:inherit;" onclick="Expand_selection(${encodedObj})">
       
                </button>
            </td>
        </tr>

    </table>
<br>
`;
}
```

and then in your `Expand_selection` function (which could be `expandedSelection`):

```
function Expand_selection(encodedObject) {
  var object = JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent(encodedObject))
  console.log(object) // should work now
  // Do other stuff.
}
```

Hope this works out, let me know if it does :)

answer reference: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66745585/20769551) by @[João Pimentel Ferreira](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1243247/jo%C3%A3o-pimentel-ferreira)

Comment: I have tested it out and it seem to work :)
Is there any particular reason why javascript is being so weird about passing object to onclick function?

Comment: No idea, but I do most of my projects with react js and I don't often have these kind of issues. Maybe cause everything is basically JavaScript, so all that stringify - parse gist isn't really necessary for passing arguments like that ‍♂️